# inner query executed independently takes longer than the overall query

Tags: sql-server

I executed a query and found that if i execute inner query independently it takes longer to execute.

My query is

```
select distinct 
   SUBSTRING(UserUri,CHARINDEX('@',UserUri)+1,LEN(UserUri)) as Company
FROM 
   [DWH].[dbo].[UsersDetails]
where 
   UserUri not like '%@mycompany.com%'
   and UserId in (
    select distinct UserId from UsersInfo
    )
   and ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(UserUri,CHARINDEX('@',UserUri)+1,LEN(UserUri)))!= 1
```

Overall query took 18-20 seconds to run. but when executed inner query i.e. ( select distinct UserId from Users ) independently it took 40-50 seconds.

My doubt is if inner query takes 40-50 seconds, outer query should be ending after that only.

Comment: that's because when an execution plan is created, the entire inner query doesn't necessarily need to be performed, all that needs to be checked  is that UserId is in UsersInfo, and that may well be possible with a seek via an index - my advice is to compare query execution plans for the two cases

Comment: You should not even use `UserId in (select ...` structure, and you should not use distinct either.

Comment: Sql doesn't work as C or other languages do. It either can use cycle in inner select or not. It can just find the one value in index, not watch all values for distincting them. It near to breaking cycle while the first match found.

Comment: I would guess that the query engine is smart enough to not use the distinct when checking `in ()`. If it is `in (distinct)` then it will also be `in ()` and the distinct check can take a long time on large tables depending on indexing. @Andrew has good advice...check the query plan.

Comment: Thanks for replies, execution plans helped me understand things. but if i dont have to put indexes are there any other means to improvise such queries.